# How to execute cmd.exe with arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to run `cmd.exe` with argument `ls`.

I used the below code

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe', 'ls'])
```

After executing this `cmd.exe` is opening but not taking `ls` as input

Comment: because `ls` is not a recognized command in Windows.

Comment: `ls` is not available. Why don't you use the `os` package?

Comment: Does `ls` work when you input it into a cmd shell ?

Answer (score 8):

There are two mistake in your script

1. `ls` not supported in windows use `dir` instead
2. `/C` parameter needed to run a command

Modified script is

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', '/C', 'dir'])
```

Note: Use `\` to escape backslash character

Comment: I got the below code from somewhere and tried and is working  code subprocess.Popen(['cmd','/K','cd ..'])

Answer (score 2):

If you add argument shell=True, python will use default shell which is available. In this case, python will use Windows cmd. In other word, below code should work:

```
>>> subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , it doesn't work with windows , if you want to use linux syntax in windows you have to use cygwin environment. or change command "ls" to "dir" ("dir /w")