# how to execute cmd commands with variables in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shell, cmd

I am iterating over the column to get parameters and passing different parameters each time to the command

```
"python GetInterfaces.py --f1 ids --f2 ids --c1 A --c2  B --c 4.5 --i 10.0 --jobid out"
```

ids, A, and B are the python variable I am getting from the data frame. I want to execute the command on the command prompt using python. I have tried with the subprocess and couldn't get how to pass the variable.
I am running the following command:

```
for x in range(3):
    ids = str(df['#Pdb'][x]) + ".pdb"
    A =  str(df["Alpha"][x])
    B = str(df["Beta"][x])
    C = str(df["Mutation(s)_PDB"][x])
    position = C[2:-1]
    call(["python", "GetInterfaces.py", "--f1", ids, "--f2", ids, "--c1", A, "--c2", B,  "--c", "4.5", "--i", "10.0", "--jobid", "out"])
```

I have also attached the snapshot of the data frame value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t44sD.png)

Comment: what's "call"?  Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012431/how-to-execute-cmd-exe-with-arguments-in-python ? what error are you getting?

Comment: the call is from the subprocess. i.e., subprocess.call and I'm neither getting any error nor any output

Comment: Can you somehow make this a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?